# Is it possible to broaden the scope of tag searching with the Vim Tagbar plugin?

Tags: vim, ctags, tagbar

I am using the plugin [Tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) (with [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/)) to help browse C source code in Vim. Things work great for a single file, but I would like to broaden the scope of the tag searching so that I can see/jump to declarations and definitions in included files. Is this possible, or am I limited to seeing the tags of a single file at a time?

Further, if there is a better way to browse declarations and definitions of large C repositories with Vim, please let me know! I am quite familiar with vscode and use that frequently, but wanted to give Vim a try.

Comment: Don't know about Tagbar, but for ctags you probably want `-R`.

Comment: If you are using git you might want to read https://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html